# Transferring files using Telnet

Tags: ftp, telnet

Is it possible to transfer files between two machines using Telnet protocol. From wikipedia,I understand that FTP & Telnet are similar. But on logging in using Telnet its very similar to logging into guest machine.

Please advise.

Comment: In principle it is possible since the FTP control connection is basically just a Telnet session. However, in order to transfer data over FTP you will need *two* connections, the Telnet/control connection and the data transfer connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot transfer a raw binary file over telnet because there are some codes that are reserved and will be escaped before transmission.  Your local telnet terminal would also interpret other codes as cursor control sequences and go wild.

So **no** `cat stuff.zip` and extracting it locally from the log file or screen cut/paste.

However, you could encode a file into something safe using uuencode or base64, capture that on the local side, and decode it using the appropriate tool to get the original binary back.

But in short, just use FTP in "binary" plus "passive" mode.  That's safest and what it's designed for.

That said, you *should* be using SSH instead of Telnet and then you can use SCP to transfer files.